# jQuery andSelf() method not working

Tags: jquery

The following code changes add and removes a css class on mouseenter and mouseleave. I am trying to include the current element along with previous siblings with andSelf() but it does not seem to work as I currently understand it from the jQuery documentation.

Code without works but not include the current element.

```
    $(function () {
        // will execute when the page is ready
        $('.rating-circle').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).prevAll().addClass('rating-hover');
        }).mouseleave(function(){
           $(this).prevAll().removeClass('rating-hover'); 
        });
    });
```

Now with the andSelf() but now will not do anything.

```
    $(function () {
        // will execute when the page is ready
        $('.rating-circle').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-hover');
        }).mouseleave(function(){
           $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('rating-hover'); 
        });
    });
```

Here are the div tags I'm trying to change. I want to change the class for all previous tags and include the current tag moused over.

```
<div id="rating-container">
<div class="rating-circle"></div>
<div class="rating-circle"></div>
<div class="rating-circle"></div>
<div class="rating-circle"></div>
<div class="rating-circle"></div>
```

Comment: `$(this).prevAll().andSelf()` should generate a jQuery collection that includes all the elements from `prevAll()` plus `this`.  Is that what you want?  If not, what are you expecting it to do?  Also, note that `.andSelf()` is deprecated now and is replaced with `.addBack()`.  It should logically be the same as `$(this).prevAll().add(this)` which might be a little more obvious in the code.  If this is not getting what you want, then you may have to show us your HTML because you may have some wrong assumptions about something related to how jQuery interacts with your HTML.

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? I put up a sample fiddle. It works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/tajqmmvs/

Comment: example : $("p").find("a").andSelf() indicates that p and a are selected. [link](http://www.developertut.com/jquery/jquery-concatenation)

Answer (score 1):

I changed andSelf() to addBack(). It works now.

```
  $(function () {
    // will execute when the page is ready
    $('.rating-circle').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).prevAll().addBack().addClass('rating-hover');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).prevAll().addBack().removeClass('rating-hover'); 
    });
});
```